# Weird behaviour of calculations with C and ctypes

Tags: python, c, ctypes

I have a C-extention whichI call in python via ctypes.
The C-Code looks like this:

```
double new(int t){
   double sum;
   sum = (double)t*(double)1.5;
   return sum;
}
```

The Python-Code like this:

```
import ctypes
fun = ctypes.CDLL("C:/test.so")
fun.new.argtypes = [ctypes.c_int]
fun.new.restypes = ctypes.c_double
fun.new(2)
```

So one would expect the output to be "3.0" but I get the output "-1398886288".
I broke it down to this easy example. My actual application is much bigger, but there I also get some weird outputs. Maybe I get somethind wrong with the ctypes?

Comment: Where is the output printed?

Comment: If the square braces are required, as in `[ctypes.c_int]`, then why are they not around `ctypes.c_double`? (As you see, I know nothing about ctypes in Python).

Comment: OT: calling a product `sum` is weird.

Comment: I print it in a jupyter-notebook.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Because argtypes is required to be a sequence and restypes only a single var.

Comment: The `Where is the output printed?` question I think is asking _where in the_ `python` _code is the print statement?_

Comment: @PaulOgilvie if you think about it is obvious: a function can have multiple arguments but just one output. So arguments make sense as a list, output doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s spelled `restype`, not `restypes`:

```
fun.new.restype = ctypes.c_double
```

With this change, the code “works”. But it doesn’t calculate a “sum”, it scales a number. It also contains an unnecessary cast, and needlessly splits declaration and initialisation.

The following is generally seen as the preferred way of implementing this function:

```c
double three_halves(int x) {
    double result = x * 1.5;
    return result;
}
```

Or, if that’s really all there is to this function, omit the unnecessary intermediate variable:

```c
double three_halves(int x) {
    return x * 1.5;
}
```

Comment: Holy ****. Thank you. Sometimes I cannot see such mistakes anymore. Also thank you for the additional recommendations. I extracted the code from a much bigger script so it looks weird like this.